# Using oracle v$sga_target_advice

Tags: oracle, memory

I used the following query to analyse an Oracle Database SGA.

```
select sga_size, sga_size_factor, estd_db_time, estd_db_time, estd_physical_reads from v$sga_target_advice;
```

I should I interpret the output?

```
>   SGA_SIZE SGA_SIZE_FACTOR ESTD_DB_TIME ESTD_DB_TIME ESTD_PHYSICAL_READS
> ---------- --------------- ------------ ------------ -------------------
>      19392             .25       363933       363933            22745558
>      24240           .3125       345513       345513            22745558
>      29088            .375       342392       342392            10525950
>      33936           .4375       341815       341815            10525950
>      38784              .5       340730       340730             6383966
>      43632           .5625       340255       340255             6383966
>      48480            .625       339678       339678             4144303
>      53328           .6875       339305       339305             4144303
>      58176             .75       339305       339305             4144303
>      63024           .8125       339237       339237             3864152
>      67872            .875       339237       339237             3864152
>      72720           .9375       339237       339237             3864152
>      77568               1       339237       339237             3864152
>      82416          1.0625       339237       339237             3864152
>      87264           1.125       339237       339237             3864152
>      92112          1.1875       339237       339237             3864152
>      96960            1.25       339237       339237             3864152
>     101808          1.3125       339237       339237             3864152
>     106656           1.375       339237       339237             3864152
>     111504          1.4375       339237       339237             3864152
>     116352             1.5       339237       339237             3864152
>     121200          1.5625       339237       339237             3864152
>     126048           1.625       339237       339237             3864152
>     130896          1.6875       339237       339237             3864152
>     135744            1.75       339237       339237             3864152
>     140592          1.8125       339238       339238             3864152
>     145440           1.875       339238       339238             3864152
>     150288          1.9375       339238       339238             3864152
>     155136               2       339238       339238             3864152
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Oracle's estimates are accurate, adding SGA will have no impact.  The `SGA_SIZE_FACTOR` 1 row is your current setting.  You can see that as you slowly double your SGA (up to the final row with an `SGA_SIZE_FACTOR` of 2), the estimated database time and the number of physical reads do not decrease.  In Oracle's estimation, you could actually reduce the amount of RAM allocated to your SGA to 81.25% of your current setting without having any impact on performance.

Of course, these estimates need to be paired with human knowledge and understanding to figure out whether they really make sense.  I wouldn't go around blindly lopping 20% of a system's SGA allocation solely based on this sort of analysis unless I was pretty confident from a holistic look at the system that the SGA was over-allocated, that I had something more useful to allocate the RAM I was freeing up to, and that the workload on this system wasn't going to be increasing in the near future.